# Sinon Spy not being called with right arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, mocha.js, sinon

### Background

I am trying to learn how to do a RESTful API following the TDD paradigm by reading a book on the subject (it is in brazillian):

- https://leanpub.com/construindo-apis-testaveis-com-nodejs/read

The author encourages the use a [`sinon.js`](http://sinonjs.org/) together with [`mocha.js`](https://mochajs.org/).

I am getting close to the end, but I am failling to pass the test for my `gnomeController`.

### Problem

The problem is that I am using sinon to assert that I am calling the `gnomeController`'s `get` method using the given reponse object, which is in reallity a spy.

This spy is to make sure I call the reponse method with an "Error", but it appears I am calling the response with no arguments whatsoever, which is very confusing.

### Code

**gnomeController.js**

```
module.exports = aGnomeModel => {

    let Gnome = aGnomeModel;

    function get(req, res){
        return Gnome.find({})
            .then(gnomes => res.send(gnomes))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
    }

    return Object.freeze({
        get
    });
};
```

**gnomeTest.js**

```
const sinon = require("sinon");
const gnomesControllerFactory = require("gnomesController.js");
const Gnome = require("gnomeModel.js");

describe("Controllers: Gnomes", () => {

    describe("get() gnomes", () => {

        it("should return 400 when an error occurs", () => {
            const request = {};
            const response = {
                send: sinon.spy(),
                status: sinon.stub()
            };

            response.status.withArgs(400).returns(response);
            Gnome.find = sinon.stub();
            Gnome.find.withArgs({}).rejects("Error");

            const gnomesController = gnomesControllerFactory(Gnome);

            return gnomesController.get(request, response)
                .then(arg => {
                    console.log(arg);
                    sinon.assert.calledWith(response.send, "Error");
                });
        });
    });

});
```

### Question

I am using the latest versions of both libraries.

1. What is wrong in my code, why is the reponse being called with no arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

After much debugging, I found out that the solution is to replace:

```
 function get(req, res){
        return Gnome.find({})
            .then(gnomes => res.send(gnomes))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
    }
```

with:

```
 function get(req, res){
        return Gnome.find({})
            .then(gnomes => res.send(gnomes))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.name));
    }
```

Which is not explained in the book. Kinda wish I could give more feedback on it, but so far it is what it is.